# Buying international train tickets between Slovakia and Ukraine

Tags: trains, international-travel, ukraine, train-stations, slovakia

I am looking to travel between Kosice and Lviv by rail, and do a return trip from Kiev to Kosice 10 days later. However, international train tickets must be purchased at a ticket office. My questions are:

1. I arrive in Kosice at 0100, my desired train Kosice-Lviv departs at 1006. Can I buy a ticket for this train say a couple of hours before departure at the train station? What happens if it is sold out? Is it likely to be sold out? What time does the ticket office for international journeys open?
2. Can I buy the return ticket from Kiev-Kosice at the ticket office in Kosice? Or would it be cheaper to buy it when I arrive in Kiev?

Comment: Cross-border trains in Ukraine are much more expensive than buses. Also, there are more buses than trains, so no risk that all tickets are sold.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not buying it on the internet? That's what I did when I left Košice for Lviv two days ago...

Comment: You can't buy online tickets on slovak rail website for international travel - did you go through an online travel agent/third party retailer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) Kosice train station opens at 0345 each day. I found I could get in earlier by entering from the platform side of the station. The ticket office opened at 0600. The train was almost empty and I doubt there would be any problem with over booking based on my experience.

(2) I didn't buy the return ticket at the office. I booked an online ticket from Kiev-Chop at the [Ukrainian railways website](http://booking.uz.gov.ua/en/). I then purchased a ticket at Chop train station to get me across the border back into Slovakia.